# VBA Case Select Not Working With Text Like Evaluation And Functioning Variable

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to check for errors in a worksheet with new museum membership data.

I created a dictionary with each membership ID as the key, iterating the value to note how many rows share same membership ID. This allows me to see how many members per membership {membership id: num of members in membership}. I have verified that the dict keys and values populate correctly.

Then I loop through the dict keys and using each ID, I get the corresponding membership level (or membership type) for that id from the original sheet. I have verified that it gets the level successfully.

Once I have this, I referenced the key's value (num of members) and use a case statement to verify the number is correct for that level. (I'm also totaling number of memberships (not members) by type along the way).

**THE PROBLEM:** The Case Statements default to Case Else (where I show an error message).

I know the code is not DRY at ALL, I'll make more concise later. I appreciate any help finding the error with Case Select! Thanks in advance.

```
Sub Inc(ByRef I As Integer)
    I = I + 1
End Sub

Function FindTextRow(t) As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FoundCell As range
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set FoundCell = ws.range("A:A").Find(What:=t)
    If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        FindTextRow = FoundCell.row
    Else
        FindTextRow = 0
    End If
End Function

Sub SummarizeCardReview()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MemberCount As Integer
    Dim MembershipCount As Integer
    Dim IDArray As Variant
    Dim IDRange As Variant
    Dim sal As range
    Dim addr As range
    Dim c As range
    Dim I As Integer
    Static sal_error_count As Integer
    Static num_members_error_count As Integer
    Dim curr As Integer
    Dim membership_members_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim k As Variant
    Dim num_memberships As Integer
    Dim num_members As Integer
    Dim num_collector As Integer
    Dim num_narrator As Integer
    Dim num_guardian As Integer
    Dim num_innovator As Integer
    Dim num_luminary As Integer
    Dim num_trailblazer As Integer
    Dim num_dual_fam As Integer
    Dim num_dual_mem As Integer
    Dim num_plus As Integer
    Dim num_individual As Integer
    Dim dup_names As Integer
    
    LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Set membership_members_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    'populate membership dict during '
    For I = 2 To LastRow
        'set dict with key as membership ID and value as 1 or incremented by 1'
        m_id = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(I, 1).Value
        If membership_members_dict.Exists(m_id) <> 0 Then
            curr = membership_members_dict(m_id)
            Inc curr
            membership_members_dict(m_id) = curr
        Else
            membership_members_dict(m_id) = 1
        End If
    Next I
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C17").Value = sal_error_count
    
     ' member count for levels & errors, membership count by level '
    num_members_error_count = 0
    num_memberships = membership_members_dict.Count
    num_members_total = LastRow - 1
    num_collector = 0
    num_narrator = 0
    num_guardian = 0
    num_innovator = 0
    num_luminary = 0
    num_trailblazer = 0
    num_dual_fam = 0
    num_dual_mem = 0
    num_plus = 0
    num_individual = 0
    
    For Each k In membership_members_dict
        row = FindTextRow(k)
        num_members = membership_members_dict(k)
        If row <> 0 Then
            m_level = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 2).Value
            MsgBox m_level
            Select Case m_level
                Case m_level Like "Individual"
                    MsgBox m_level
                    Inc num_individual
                    If num_members <> 1 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Dual | Family"
                    Inc num_dual_fam
                    If num_members <> 2 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Dual Membership"
                    Inc num_dual_mem
                    If num_members <> 2 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "MOHAI Plus"
                    Inc num_plus
                    If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Collector"
                    Inc num_collector
                    If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Guardian"
                    Inc num_guardian
                     If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                     End If
                Case m_level Like "Narrator"
                    Inc num_narrator
                    If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Innovator"
                    Inc num_innovator
                    If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                    End If
                Case m_level Like "Trailblazer"
                     Inc num_trailblazer
                     If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                     End If
                Case m_level Like "Luminary"
                     Inc num_luminary
                     If num_members <> 3 Then
                        Inc num_members_error_count
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReview").Cells(row, 1).Interior.Color = vbOrange
                     End If
                Case Else
                    MsgBox ("Error")
            End Select
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox num_members_error_count
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C3").Value = num_memberships
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C4").Value = num_members_total
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C5").Value = num_collector
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C6").Value = num_guardian
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C7").Value = num_narrator
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C8").Value = num_innovator
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C9").Value = num_luminary
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C10").Value = num_trailblazer
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C11").Value = num_dual_fam
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C12").Value = num_dual_mem
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C13").Value = num_plus
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C14").Value = num_individual
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CardReviewSummary").range("C18").Value = num_members_error_count
    
    
    Msg = "Sucess! :)"
    output = MsgBox(Msg, vbInformation)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Like` without any wildcards (#, * or ? for example) is the same as `=`

Comment: Maybe you want `Select Case True` here though.  Or just `Case  "Individual"` if you're looking for exact matches.

Comment: Thanks! The ```Select Case True``` fix worked & appreciate the Like related tips, will adjust

Comment: OK - best not to use `Like` unless you need wildcard matching though - it's a bit confusing to read.

Comment: If you are a still having issues after fixing the operand in the case statements it would be helpful to get some sample data you have to get a better understanding.

Comment: I cannot see where you have declared the variable `m_level` - Put Option Explicit before your subroutine or function and declare (Dim) all variables, add some sample data. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement